# Android Studio: Duplicate files copied in APK assets

Tags: android-studio, duplicates, android-gradle-plugin

After adding these jar files project couldn't run. I am getting errors:

```
Duplicate files copied in APK assets/vg_close.png

File1: ...Temp/app/libs/vungle-publisher-adaptive-id-3.3.5.jar
File2: ...Temp/app/libs/appodeal-1.14.15.jar
```

I tried to fix with these lines in gradle but it didn't help:

```
packagingOptions {
    exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
    exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
    exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
    exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
}
```

Any idea?

Comment: Were you able to solve it by now? I have a similar issue, also with appodeal

Comment: @Marty yeap, appodeal jar contains vungle library, and you cannot use appodeal jar with vungle jar simultaneously

Comment: there were some more overlaps between jars for me. I managed to solve it by removing the specific things form the appodeal jar: zip -d jarFile.jar whatEverIWantToRemove. Maybe that helps you at some point in the future as well.

Answer (score 1):

Just so there is an answer, it is already discussed in the comments to the original post.

1. appodeal jar contains vungle library, and you cannot use appodeal jar with vungle jar simultaneously
2. if you want to keep the vungle library you can remove the files from the appodeal.jar in the terminal/console with this:

   ```
    zip -d ...Temp/app/libs/appodeal-1.14.15.jar assets/vg_close.png
   ```

and for all the others it complains or directly

```
     zip -d ...Temp/app/libs/appodeal-1.14.15.jar assets/vg*.png
```

I hope that helps someone as well.